# Java 8 and Garbage Collection

Tags: java

I have a question about Java 8 and the Garbage Collection we have a problem with an application that used to run on Java 6 with no problems and now we are having problems with Intermittent Printing the Host sends to the Applications Print messages and they work most of the time however based on the Logs it looks like when the Printer message is sent to the PrintSystem Class ( run as a separate thread ) its not responding. In doing some reading about the GC and strong and weak references it seems that the way that the PrintSystem send messages is like this

PrintSystem.getInstance().printMessage(message);

So it is possible that Java 8 is GC'ing the PrintSystem Thread due to differences between Java 6 and 8 ? Also the code was recompiled to run for Java 8, I am wondering if it should still be compiled for Java 6 and just run it on Java 8 ( if that makes sense )

**Log Data** 
07Jan 14:59:38.037 communications.headers.PLMHeader.PLMMessage() INFO userData is 25 bytes

07Jan 14:59:38.038 communications.headers.PLMHeader.PLMMessage() INFO userData is:
Test Message

07Jan 14:59:38.038 communications.ums.UMSWorker.run() INFO UMS Worker Active

07Jan 14:59:38.038 communications.ums.UMSWorker.run() INFO Received Unsolicited Message...

07Jan 14:59:38.038 communications.ums.UMSWorker.run() INFO Sending Message to print system      **( Sent from UMSWorker Thread                                                                                               Should have had a PrintSystem Response with 100ms)**

07 Jan 2019 15:00:19.365 communications.ums.UMSWorker.setAceNetHeader() INFO Data is:          **(41seconds before next message and its unrelated)**

```
public void printMessage(Object message) throws Exception
{
if (!initialized)
   throw new Exception("DEBUG: Print System not initialized!");
try 
{
 synchronized(this)
 {
  printList.add(message); // LinkedList 
  this.notify();
 }
 LogManager.traceMessage(this,"DEBUG: PrintSystem.PrintMessage()", 
"printList Size : " + printList.size());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 LogManager.traceMessage(this,"DEBUG: PrintSystem.PrintMessage() ", 
 "Exception : " + e);
}
}
```

And this is the PrintSystem run() that waits / loops to read the printList

```
public void run()
{
Object message = null;
while (true)
{
 try
 {
  synchronized(this)
  {
   this.wait(2500);
  }
}
catch (Exception e) {} 

 while (!printList.isEmpty())
 {
  synchronized(this) 
  {
    message = printList.removeFirst();
  }
  int printed = printPLMMessage((PLMHeader) message);
  PLMHeader ackHeader = generatePrinterAck((PLMHeader) 
  message,printed);
  Communications.getInstance().ack(ackHeader);
 }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Threads are garbage collection roots and can't be garbage collected. Also, I think you have to share some code.

Comment: Please try to provide a pice of (maybe simplified) code.

Comment: I will try an put in some code and log info, however the fact that Threads can be GC'd suggests that something went wrong with the Thread it could be locked ? Or something caused it to fail.

Comment: If the code has been rewritten to work on Java 8 then the problem may have been introduced there.

Comment: It only had one small change to read a properties file otherwise the Code is the same.

Comment: What class/package/framework is `PrintSystem`? I googled `java PrintSystem` and got nothing. First I thought you are printing on printer, but that uses `javax.print.PrintService`, so I am confused what exactly do you mean by printing. If it is your class, all we can see from code is you are adding message to some list, but what is done with that list?

Comment: Are you relying on the default garbage collector, or are you selecting a specific one and tuning it? Some of the tuning parameters did change between Java versions.

Comment: As for the PrintSystem that is a class that was built to determine what printer to send to it so the problem is occurring before it gets to the javax.print.PrintService. It seems the Thread is either locked or has gone missing maybe GC ? ( however I understand that GC won't remove an active Thread )

Comment: Hi Roddy, just using default GC my understanding is Java won't GC a Thread, we are having a problem with the logging and that could be a GC issue.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is not a GC issue. I think it’s a defective code issue.

The code adds things to printList with a lock held but the code reading from the printList doesn’t have the lock held when it reads. That makes this code insufficiently synchronized, so there are no guarantees about the visibility of updates to printList for the reading thread.

Apparently you got lucky previously and this code worked by accident. When you upgrade Java one of the things you get is better optimizations, that do fancy things like figuring out when they can delay updating caches or when they can rule out having to execute some code at all, and the decisions about when to invoke these optimizations have to assume the code they’re applied to is sufficiently synchronized. If the code isn’t then the optimizations can get applied in some way that isn’t what you want.

Comment: Thanks Nathan that could be that Java 8 is just exposing a problem with the code but the question that still needs to be answer ( and maybe it has been ) is would the printList ( LinkedList ) not be sync'd cause the thread to hang or fail requiring an Application recycle. I could see the lack of sync causing inaccurate data but the thread should be responding I would think ?

Comment: @Dan: there’s also an issue where notifications are getting lost because of how wait and notify arent using a condition variable. Might try rewriting using an ArrayBlockingQueue.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, currently there is a timeout on the wait so it will check every 2.5 Seconds. I will take a look at the ArrayBlockingQueue